# How to invite users to Azure AD B2C on my ReactJS SPA app with/without microsoft graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I have set up a working sign in flow using custom policies in Azure AD B2C for my Single Page Application (written in React JS). A user can only explore the different pages in my application (i.e. routes are protected by checking if the user has signed in already in Azure AD B2C, after a user signs in, I validate the user in my JS code and allow them to access the routes on my application).

Here's my current flow:

1. When the user enters the link to my website, I immediately direct them to the sign in flow in Azure AD B2C (i.e. `loginRediect` method is called.)
2. Upon successful login, user is redirected back to my application. There is a payload with the following keys that I can retrieve when the user is re-directed to my application. Here are some of the keys in the payload: `authority`, `uniqueId`, `tenantId`, `scopes`, `idTokenClaims`, `account` , etc. (I can include more keys if it helps to answer my query). This is retrieved via a callback called on the `msalInstance`.
3. Now from within my application, I would like to allow users to invite other users by providing their email address, so that they can use my application as well.

What I have tried to do to invite users, is to retrieve an `accessToken` to call the Microsoft Graph API for inviting users (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0), (I allowed `User.Invite.All` in my registered app for my Single Page Application in the API Permissions tab.) But when I call the method `acquireTokenSilent` to try to request the accessToken to call the Microsoft Graph API, I get an  as my accessToken. So there's no way I can even attempt to call the Invitation API.

My question would be how then can I invite new users into B2C?  Because it seems like I cannot use the Microsoft Graph API to invite B2C users for my application?

If you need any other details please do ask.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using the Graph API is the best way to proceed in this case, because using the Graph API you could either create a guest user (not an AD B2C user) or create a new AD B2C user, but you would have to provide the required information (password, name, etc).

A better approach is to send an email, which allows the user to sign-up using the B2C sign-up policy.
Check out this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite), which describes how to generate a sign-up link and use it in the sign-up policy, so that the users don't need to verify their email addresses again.